Charging time in a series-parallel battery setup
So I am trying to figure out how long it would take for 24 batteries (1.5 V, 3 Ah each) to be charged from 10% to 100%. The batteries would be set up so there are 3 rows of 8 batteries in series, connected together in parallel. This diagram shows the setup I am talking about.

Disregarding battery degradation and other complications (as this set up is not a physical one, just a hypothetical one), how long would it take for a 3 V, 1 A charger to charge all of these batteries from 10% to 100% (assuming I connect to the "main" outputs on the right and left side of the photo)?
I am sort of confused as if each battery was being charged at the same time at the same rate (1A) it would take ~2.7 Hrs to charge everything from 10% to max, but that doesn't seem right to me. I feel like it would still have to charge each battery "individually" in a sense, like it would take each battery 2.7 Hrs, for a total of 64.8 Hrs. Is this correct?

What rechargeable chemistry has a 1.5 V nominal voltage?


how long would it take for a 3 V, 1 A charger to charge all of these batteries

It would never finish charging them, because there's no battery chemistry that is fully charged at 3V / 8, but that's the voltage seen by the individual cell in a series of 8 cells. That is, assuming cell balancing, which your circuit also doesn't have.
So, this doesn't work.

Your diagram shows 24 cells arranged as an 8s3p battery.  Putting 8 cells (1.5 volts each) in series gives you a 12 volt battery.  To charge a 12 volt battery, you need at least 12 volts.  So, your 3 volt charger will not be able to charge them at all.
You could trade the 3 volt charger for a 12 volt one.  By using 4 times the voltage, you are able to produce 4 times the power.  It's a bigger power supply.  This is why the battery would appear to charge in less time than you imagined the 3 volt would take.
Purely as an engineering exercise, you could get some kind of device to step up your 3v supply to 12v.  But the power into a converter is the same as the power out, so at 12v you would get only 0.25A.  And so the battery would charge that much slower.  In practice, this is a bad idea because of the losses in conversion, so it would perform quite a bit worse.
The easy part of the calculations occur when you make 3 of these and then put them in parallel.  The current divides up among the 3 "strings", with each one getting a third, and so together the parallel combination takes 3 times as long to charge as a single string.
